# Using multiple conditions within where statement

Tags: sql, sas, where-clause

I am trying to identify the number of people (based on ID) who are present in all 3 "touch"es AND opened (open=1) all 3 emails. I am using the below code, but it returns a value of 0 which I don't believe is true. So, I'm not sure that I am representing this correctly in the data.

```
proc sql;
    select count (ID) 
    from TableX 
    where (Touch='Touch1' and Open=1) and (Touch='Touch2' and Open=1) and (Touch='Touch3' and Open=1);
    quit;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thing about your query logically. Is it possible for `Touch` to be equal to `Touch1` AND `Touch2` at the same time? That's what your query is doing.

Comment: You possibly need `OR` between the parentheses pairs. Or use `IN()` on *Touch1-3* with AND for *Open*.

Comment: I am looking for people who are in all three touches, so I don't think or would work here. I also tried the in statement and that returned the whole dataset, so I am guessing that works as or instead of and.

Answer (score 5):

You can identify the people using:

```
proc sql;
    select id
    from TableX 
    where Open = 1 and Touch in ('Touch1', 'Touch2', 'Touch3')
    group by id
    having count(distinct Touch) = 3;
    quit;
```

To count them, use a subquery:

```
proc sql;
    select count(*)
    from (select id
          from TableX 
          where Open = 1 and Touch in ('Touch1', 'Touch2', 'Touch3')
          group by id
          having count(distinct Touch) = 3
         ) x
    quit;
```

Comment: I never didn't see an expression like ` having count(distinct touch = 3)`

Comment: With this query I get this error: ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types

Comment: please check count(distinct Touch) = 3 instead of count(distinct Touch = 3)